# The 7 Essential Meta Questions for Sustainable Living Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, 7-questions

Given the [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) I think it is worth having a place where we can link together these essential meta questions.

The 7 Essential Questions of Every Beta are:

1. Are questions about [subject] on or off topic?

   - See the [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) tag, for example:
   - [How do we handle Permaculture questions with respect to Gardening SE?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/37/164)
   - [What makes a question belong here as opposed to Home Improvement or Personal Finance and Money?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/52/164)
2. What should our FAQ contain?

   - See [What should our FAQ contain?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/164)
   - See also questions tagged with [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag.
3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?

   - See the [tagging](/questions/tagged/tagging), [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) and [retagging](/questions/tagged/retagging) tags, for example:
   - [What the difference between the 'urban' and 'city-living' tags?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33/164)
   - [Tags diy and homemade seem to overlap](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34/164)
   - [What should be the animal related tag(s) for this site?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12/164)
4. Who should the moderators be?

   - See [Who should our beta moderators be?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/62/164)
   - See also questions tagged with the [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) tag.
5. What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

   - See [What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/60/164)
6. What should our logo and site design look like?

   - See [What should our logo and site design look like?](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/183/48)
7. How do we promote our site?

   - See questions tagged with the [site-promotion](/questions/tagged/site-promotion) tag.